# What does `%f[%]` means in lua

Tags: lua

In Programming in Lua, 4th Edition, there is a code snippet

```lua
for w in string.gmatch(s, "]=*%f[%]]") do
    n = math.max(n, #w - 1)
end
```

which find the maximum number of `=` between two `]`, the author says the frontier pattern is needed because the simpler pattern like `]=*]` gives `n = 1` while matching `]=]==]` instead of the desired `n = 2`. what is the `%f[%]` means?

Answer (score 0):

`[%]]` matches a single character `]`

`%f[%]]` is the frontier pattern of `[%]]`, it matches a position that its next character is `]` and the previous character is not `]`.

It is similar to `[^%]]*[%]]`. The difference is `[^%]]*[%]]` matches  characters but `%f[%]]` matches a position.